# Is this ArcGIS url still supported?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

I have a old web service that is pointing to this url:

```
http://geocode.arcgis.com:80/arcgis/services/World/GeocodeServer
```

However, it stopped working today giving a 400 Bad Request Error.
Has this url been deprecated?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue suddenly (specifically for the reverseGeocode endpoint)

Comment: @TheProgrammer I want to know if this API is free to use or not ?

Comment: @J4GD33P51NGH I believe its free but they limit the number of times you can Geocode. I would suggest reaching out to customer support for ESRI

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Esri, the company behind ArcGIS, to figure out the issue. They recently switched their systems over to HTTPS, so that's what's causing the error.

Here's an example working URL:

https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/reverseGeocode?f=json&location=-71.4225,42.3888

And the response:

[image: REST response]

Comment: Thank you for this info. In addition to adding https I also noticed the "rest" in the url. It looks like it is pointing to the RESTful API on their end, my original url does not include "rest"

Comment: is it free ? any sources ?